# run time error with respect to execution of randomized quicksort

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c++11, quicksort

I’m trying to implement randomized version of quicksort. I have successfully used the normal version of quicksort, but now the g++ compiler says floating point exception (core dumped). How do I proceed?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void qsort(int* a,int start,int end);

int part(int*a,int start, int end);

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    cout<<"enter no of elements...."<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    cout<<"enter the elements to be sorted"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    int start=0;
    qsort(a,start,n-1);
    cout<<"the list is..";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';
    return 0;
}

void qsort(int* a,int start,int end)
{
    if(end>start)
    {
        int pi=part(a,start,end);
        qsort(a,start,pi-1);
        qsort(a,pi+1,end);
    }
}

int part(int*a,int start, int end)
{
    int pi,pivot,k;

    int i=start+rand()%(start+end-1);
    pi=start;       
    pivot=a[i];
    int j,t;

    for(j=start;j<end;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]<=pivot)
        {
            t=a[j];
            a[j]=a[pi];
            a[pi]=t;
            pi++;
        }
    }
    t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[pi];
    a[pi]=t;

    return pi;
}
```

Comment: `How do i proceed`  With a debugger.  Find the line that causes the floating point exception and examine the values causing the error.

Comment: Did you ensure that the right side of this expression `int i=start+rand()%(start+end-1);` is never `0`?

Comment: It it just me, or is this neither c nor c++? The I/O-streams are *definitely* not c, and the variable-length array doesn't look c++ to me.

Comment: See case when `start-end=1` then in `int i=start+rand()%(start+end-1); ` it would be a problem.

Comment: EOF: It's not standard C++, but in gcc, VLA is a permitted extension for C++ programs

Comment: I get an `ìnteger dividion by zero` at this line: `int i=start+rand()%(start+end-1);` if `start+end-1` is zero. If your program doesn't stop because of the zero division, the content of `i` will be undefined leading to undefined behaviour when you try to use `i` as an index into the `a` buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but now the g++ compiler says floating point exception (core dumped)

No, the compiler didn't say that, the actual program did, because it is crashing. You should run it through `gdb` or similar instead. If you do you will get something like this:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000400bf2 in part(int*, int, int) ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400bf2 in part(int*, int, int) ()
#1  0x0000000000400b9c in qsort(int*, int, int) ()
#2  0x0000000000400bb6 in qsort(int*, int, int) ()
#3  0x0000000000400b0d in main ()
(gdb)
```

So the problem is in the `part` function.
The most obvious suspect is `int i=start+rand()%(start+end-1);` as pointed out in comments, if divisor is `0` you will crash. Its up to you to figure it out.